# Haxe OpenFL stablexui project, error Widget class is not registered: meta: include. Why?

Tags: xml, haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, stablexui

I develop flash application using OpenFL + stablexui for Haxe to FlashDevelop. Once I started using the tag `<meta: include>` in index.xml interface markup file, then immediately began to appear an error when connecting to the project xml file with the text:

> Widget class is not registered: meta:include

Haxe version 3.2.1

versions of the libraries used in the project:

```
<haxelib name="openfl"   version="4.5.2"/>
<haxelib name="buddy"    version="2.6.0"/>
<haxelib name="mockatoo" version="3.2.1"/>
<haxelib name="hscript"  version="2.0.7"/>

<haxelib name="actuate"   version="1.8.7"/>
<haxelib name="stablexui" version="1.2.0"/>
<haxelib name="promhx"    version="1.1.0"/>
<haxelib name="svg"       version="1.1.1"/>
```

Part of the code of the main class initialization:

```
import flash.Lib;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.system.Capabilities;
import flash.text.Font;

import openfl.Lib;
import openfl.display.*;
import openfl.system.System;
import openfl.events.MouseEvent;

import ru.stablex.ui.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.RTXml;
import ru.stablex.ui.UIBuilder;
import ru.stablex.ui.skins.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.widgets.*;
import ru.stablex.ui.events.WidgetEvent;


class AppMain extends Sprite {
public function new() {
super();

LocalState.sharedObjectName = "state.startproject";

//----------------
//-- Init App
//----------------


UIBuilder.regClass('AppMain');
UIBuilder.init("ui/skins/defaults.xml");
UIBuilder.regSkins("ui/skins/skins.xml");

UIBuilder.buildFn("ui/index.xml")();
}
}
```

Part of the XML code index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ViewStack id="'screens'" widthPt="100" trans:Slide-direction="'left'" trans:Slide-duration="0.2">
    <meta:include src="ui/start.xml" />
    <meta:include src="ui/content.xml" />
</ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem in the library which I connected to the functional. stablex nothing to do with.